# Transfinite induction without successor of a limit ordinal.

Tags: set-theory

Suppose I have some statement $P(\beta)$ where $\beta$ is an ordinal.

Suppose further that

- $P(\emptyset)$ is true;
- $P(\beta) \implies P(\beta +1)$ for $\beta$ a successor ordinal; and
- $P(\lambda)$ is true for $\lambda$ a limit orindal.

Is this enough data to specify that $P(\beta)$ is true for all $\beta$? Essentially, can transfinite induction be done without checking the case for successors of limit ordinals?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Certainly **not** - consider the property "is not the successor of an infinite limit ordinal." $0$ has this property, as does any successor-of-a-successor ordinal and any limit ordinal, but not every ordinal has this property.

While this may seem silly, it's a perfectly valid counterexample.